# trouble to install spaCy 3.0 on GoogleColab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, spacy

### Background

I'm woking on the following local environment and need to use spaCy 3.0 on GoogleColab.

However, it looks accepted to install spaCy after 3.0 because of python version.

```
spaCy version    3.0.5                         
Python version   3.9.1
```

### Error

How can I use spaCy after 3.0 on GoogleColab or is it impossible now?

```
Requirement already satisfied: spacy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (2.2.4)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 3.0.5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for 3.0.5
```

### Environment

GoogleColab

```
!pip install spacy
!python -m spacy info
============================== Info about spaCy ==============================

spaCy version    2.2.4                         
Python version   3.7.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pip` to install spaCy, and specify version 3.1.1

```
!pip install spacy==3.1.1
```

Then you can check the result.

```
import spacy
print(spacy.__version__)  # 3.1.1
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `pip install XXX`, pip will not upgrade something you already have installed by default. To update it use the `-U` (or `--update`) flag.

```
pip install -U spacy
```

That should install the latest version.